# Jquery Star Rating Plugin - Half star Not Working

Tags: jquery, rating

I am implementing [jquery star rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/).

a single star imputing is workign fine, no problem.
But i cant seem to get half a star working...

html source:

```
<div class="stars">
   <span class="star-rating-control"><div class="rating-cancel" style="display: none;"><a title="Cancel Rating"></a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 required {half:true} star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="Answer1_Rating"><a title="1">1</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 required {half:true} star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="Answer1_Rating"><a title="2">2</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 required {half:true} star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="Answer1_Rating"><a title="3">3</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 required {half:true} star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="Answer1_Rating"><a title="4">4</a></div><div role="text" aria-label="" class="star-rating rater-0 required {half:true} star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="Answer1_Rating"><a title="5">5</a></div></span>
   <input class="required  {half:true} star-rating-applied" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Rating field is required." id="Answer1_Rating" name="Answer1.Rating" type="radio" value="1" style="display: none;">
   <input class="required  {half:true} star-rating-applied" id="Answer1_Rating" name="Answer1.Rating" type="radio" value="2" style="display: none;">
   <input class="required  {half:true} star-rating-applied" id="Answer1_Rating" name="Answer1.Rating" type="radio" value="3" style="display: none;">
   <input class="required  {half:true} star-rating-applied" id="Answer1_Rating" name="Answer1.Rating" type="radio" value="4" style="display: none;">
   <input class="required  {half:true} star-rating-applied" id="Answer1_Rating" name="Answer1.Rating" type="radio" value="5" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $('.stars :radio').rating();
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle for us please ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/MmGxp/

Comment: There you go, i think im missing something obvious but cant work out what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ :

> Use metadata plugin to pass advanced settings to the plugin via the class property.

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata

Answer (score 0):

@mfo's link isn't working anymore. It seems that it is here now.

https://github.com/jquery-orphans/jquery-metadata

I used it and it is working for me.